# Unable to delete project completely from application in Jdeveloper 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, soa, jdeveloper, osb

I am trying to delete a project from an application in Jdeveloper 12c IDE , but complete deletion is not working [delete all its contents (including source directories)], only project removal is working.

Comment: Can you tell us your exact JDev version, please? What do you mean by '..complete deletion...? what is the difference to '...removal is working?

Comment: Jdev  version : 12.2.1.4.0 , 
i can remove project from application , but cannot remove project and delete all its contents (including source directories).